# "Приложение не отвечает" при получении данных с базы SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, maui

Хочу заполнить `ListView` объект данными из бд, однако при получении этих данных приложение зависает. В логах никаких ошибок нет. Есть предположение, что общение с бд происходит в UI потоке, хотя вроде бы все методы объявляю, как `async`.

ContentPage, при открытии которого зависает приложение:

```
public PollsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        getPolls();
        
    }

    public async Task getPolls()
    {
        Database.SmartYardDB db = new Database.SmartYardDB();
        if(db.getNotAnsweredPolls().Result != null)
            lvPolls.ItemsSource = (IList<Models.Tables.Polls>)db.getNotAnsweredPolls().Result;
    }
```

Методы внутри класса бд:

```
public SQLiteAsyncConnection db;

        public async Task init()
        {
            if (db is not null)
            {
                return;
            }

            db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.Database.DatabasePath, Constants.Database.Flags);
            await db.CreateTableAsync<Models.Tables.Users>();
            await db.CreateTableAsync<Models.Tables.Messages>();
            await db.CreateTableAsync<Models.Tables.Polls>();
        }

public async Task<List<Models.Tables.Polls>> getNotAnsweredPolls()
        {
            await init();
            return await db.Table<Models.Tables.Polls>().Where(
                x => x.userAnswer != Constants.Database.POLLS_USERANSWER_NOTANSWERED &&
                x.status == Constants.Database.POLLS_STATUS_ACTIVE).ToListAsync();

        }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делаю неправильно. Спасибо)

Comment: `.Result` - где же он асинхронный?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov мне же по идее нужно как-то объект из Task'a получить, подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать правильно?

Comment: Когда вы пишете `async` без `await` - это тоже самое, что у вас будет простой синхронный метод. Используя `.Result` вы ждете синхронно эту задачу, это плохо, ужасно. Я так понял, вы не понимаете как там "прицепить" `await` - да все просто, сделайте отдельно `var result = await db.getNotAnsweredPolls();`, ну или оберните это, например так `if ((await db.getNotAnsweredPolls()) is not null){ .. }`. И да, помните про [соглашения именования](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions), в C# как пишете вы, мало кто пишет)

Comment: Везде и всегда использовать `await`.

Comment: `lvPolls.ItemsSource = (await db.getNotAnsweredPolls()) as IList<Models.Tables.Polls>;` а условие перед этим вообще убрать.

Comment: `getPolls();` не пишите код в конструкторе окна. Есть куча событий, которые возникают во время жизни приложения. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/app-lifecycle - возмите хотя-бы `Created`. Но не в кострукторе это надо делать. И надо `await getPolls();`

Comment: ...или если это ContentPage, то событие `Appearing` подойдет.